# How clear routing cache in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, routes

I override routing loader (routing.loader) for set requirements key {_locale} in all my paths and set defaults this key. All locales saved in database. And i want clear routing cache (Matcher and Dumper cache class) after save new locale in database, because requirements parameter load from DB.

Thank.

Answer (score 8):

Symfony cached route files:

appDevUrlMatcher.php
appDevUrlGenerator.php

in your cache dir, var/cache/dev(prod)

just delete these files

```
 protected function warmUpRouteCache() {

    $router = $this->get('router');
    $filesystem = $this->get('filesystem');
    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
    $cacheDir = $kernel->getCacheDir();

    foreach (array('matcher_cache_class', 'generator_cache_class') as $option) {
        $className = $router->getOption($option);
        $cacheFile = $cacheDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $className . '.php';
        $filesystem->remove($cacheFile);
    }

    $router->warmUp($cacheDir);
}
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console cache:clear --help
```

Additional cache warm up tasks are executed after clearing the cache in order to have regenerated caches available during runtime - see detailed help for further information.

- https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/usage.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/console/usage.html